# Not looping through all the files

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-rename

**Windows batch script:**
I have three files in a drectory.I`m trying to loop through the multiple files located in the directory and rename the files,but some how its not looping through.
i can see that the **var1** is getting the right file name but not for **sub1**.This in turn renames the other two files in the directory with wrong output. Could some one please help me on this.

```
@echo on & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 

set a=9
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /b "C:\XX\YY\ZZ*"') do ( 
set var1=%%i
 SET sub1=%var1:~7,22%
 ECHO %sub1% 
  ren "%%i" "ABC!sub1!_!a!.dat" 
  set /a a+=1
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo on
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 
set a=10001 
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /b "C:\TEST\PBM\PAR*"') do ( 
set var1=%%i
 SET sub1=!var1:~7,22!
 ECHO !sub1!
  ECHO ren "%%i" "ABC!sub1!_!a!.dat" 
  set /a a+=1
)
```

With `delayedexpansion` any reference to the value of a variable that is changed within the loop must use the `!var!` syntax. `%var%` will access the **parse-time** value.

Note: REN is now `echo`ed for verification.